# Use virtual machine display in docker

Tags: ros, ros2, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to start GUI apps like rviz using ros2-eloquent docker image.

My setup consists in a simple VirtualBox Ubuntu 18.04 setup.

Is there any need to rebuild from scratch using a Dockerfile ? or just a specific parameter to docker run ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369495/use-virtual-machine-display-in-docker/) by [coiedulci](https://answers.ros.org/users/67824/coiedulci/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-01-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not clear but I'm assuming you're running docker inside of your VirtualBox VM.

With that in mind there's several ways to approach this documented here: http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/GUI

The simplest way is to use [rocker](https://github.com/osrf/rocker).

Whichever approach you choose, you may have performance issues stemming from the multiple layers of virtualization and trying to get 3D accelerated graphics passed through fully. It's certainly not been tested in that configuration.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2021-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1